# How to load images on each small cubie on Rubik Cube using THREE JS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have to develop a 5x5 rubik cube, cube has 6 faces, so I have to display 25 images on each small box on each face (total of 150 images in the entire 5x5 cube). Rubik cube is displayed perfectly, but when I insert images, nothing is displayed not even the cube.

```
//5x5x5 rubik cube is constructed here...
for(var i = 0; i < dimensions; i ++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < dimensions; j ++) {
      for(var k = 
      0; k < dimensions; k ++) {

        var x = (i - positionOffset) * increment,
            y = (j - positionOffset) * increment,
            z = (k - positionOffset) * increment;

        newCube(x, y, z);
      }
    }
  }


//newCube function...

function newCube(x, y, z) {
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  const cubeMaterials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-1.jpg')}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-2.jpg')}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-3.jpg')}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-4.jpg')}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-5.jpg')}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-6.jpg')}),
  ];
    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry,cubeMaterials);
    cube.castShadow = true;

    cube.position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
    cube.rubikPosition = cube.position.clone();

    cube.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      onCubeMouseDown(e, cube);
    });

    cube.on('mouseup', function(e) {
      onCubeMouseUp(e, cube);
    });

    cube.on('mouseout', function(e) {
      onCubeMouseOut(e, cube);
    });

    scene.add(cube);
    allCubes.push(cube);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Just passing multiple materials as an array is not enough, you should create an instance of `MeshFaceMaterial` and pass it as the final material to your mesh:

```
var cubeMaterials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: image1}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: image2}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: image3}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: image4}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: image5}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: image6}),
];
cubeMaterials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( cubeMaterials );
```

[Here is an example of how it should be done](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agEJmE?editors=0010)

Another important thing to notice is that having 5x5x5 cube - it's **750** calls to texture loader. Preload your assets before actually using them.